# SQLAlchemy: Return default value for column_property

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am defining an SQLAlchemy [`column_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_columns.html#sqlalchemy.orm.column_property) based on a [`select`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select) (with a [`coerced type`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.type_coerce)). How can I define a default type for the `column_property` to return? Usually it returns a list of lists, but if the `select` doesn't find anything, then it returns `None`. Instead I would like it to return an empty list (`[]`). Some example code:

```
def get_list(cls_type):
    select_list = select([cls_type.foo]).select_from(cls_type)
    select_list = select_list.correlate_except(cls_type).label('foo_list')
    coerce_array_select = select([type_coerce(func.array(select_list), ListColumnProp(Text))])
    return column_property(coerce_array_select, deferred=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out -- this knowledge is embedded in the [`TypeEngine`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_api.html#sqlalchemy.types.TypeEngine) class, in the above case `ListColumnProp`. In this case, it is implemented via a child class of `TypeEngine` -- [`TypeDecorator`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator). So for example:

```
class ListColumnProp(TypeDecorator):
    impl = ARRAY

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value:
            return [tuple(json.loads(v)) for v in value]
        else:
            return []
```